# Ubuntu Legacy install on GPT based Disk

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios, gpt, mbr

I have a very peculiar condition where I need GPT based disk for hackintosh. I also want to install the following distros:

```
* Ubuntu 16.04
* Elementary OS Luna (Ubuntu 12 based)
```

I'm pretty confused by now as to whether I can install the above using legacy boot on GPT partition. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to just use EFI? It's more stable.

Comment: Because I have a Dell 15R N5110. It does not support EFI or that's what my research has told me

Comment: [Here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) some good information about the topic. Ubuntu and Elementary can be installed in UEFI-mode. If MacOS is installed in UEFI-mode it will be less headache to install other OS in UEFI-mode too.

Comment: @mook765 I have BIOS and the last update Dell gave was A11. Is there anything I can do to make my laptop UEFI compatible without a lot of effort?

Comment: If the computer does not support UEFI it will be impossible to install in UEFI-mode, only legacy-mode possible. No chance to make the computer UEFI-compatible. I am not sure if you can boot from GPT-drive with this machine, I never tried that, so try and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Legacy can be installed on a `GPT` Partition Table disk format.  By the way, it's the new standard that's gradually replacing `MBR`.  This format type is a better choice because it doesn't have the `MBR` limits.

Read and booting to GPT Partition table drives are compatible with all Intel-based computers since 2003.  It's quiet unlikely that you will find a PC that can't read the format.

**Results of Copy from `MBR` to `GPT`:**

I used `dd` to copy a partition from source drive in `MBR` and destination drive in `GPT` partition.  The only partition that was affected was the destination partition on the destination drive.  All the other partitions on the destination drive remained in tact.

The destination drive was a bootable drive with a `GPT` partition table.  The OS on the 120G drive is Ubuntu 16.04.  The drive boots in either a computer that has `EFI` compatible or just `legacy`.  I tested booting the drive to a 10 year old Dell laptop, that only has legacy support.  It booted flawlessly before the copy and after the copy to the Laptop, as my computer that has the `UEFI` capability.

**DD Copy Script**

When I perform what I consider critical task such as this, I usually create a `very easy to follow` script first and study it closely and run the critical command from the script.  Also I have a huge command history buffer, and try to minimize accidentally running a wrong commandline from the history.  I call the script from the directory with: `./ddcopy.sh`

The script I used is:
`ddcopy.sh:`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source="/dev/sdb1"
destination="/dev/sdc4"

read -p "Copy from device $source to $destination: [y/n] " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    # do dangerous stuff
    echo "..."
    echo "Proceeding..."
    time sudo dd if="$source" of="$destination" bs=4M status=progress ; espeak "Application Completed."
else
    echo "..."
    echo "Applicaton canceled."
fi
```

After the copy I used `gparted` edit's `check` command to correct the integrity of the partition.  The two partition sizes were different.  While the disk mounted and the data's checksum was correct, the `check` corrected the size discrepancy.

**Integrity of the Files verification**

I ran a `checksum` check of the files on the source and and the destination partitions to ensure the integrity of the  files transferred.  I also performed before and after checksum test of the destination drive to ensure the other partitions remained unaffected after the `dd` copy.

An example of the multiple `checksum` test is:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
$ md5sum /mnt/* >> ~/checklist2.chk ; espeak "Application completed"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, helped a lot. One more thing, I already have Ubuntu and elemntary installs whose /home folders I want to migrate to my new GPT based installs. Would you recommend [Ubuntu /home migration guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) or dd? I'm confused because right now obviously the /home folders are on MBR based partitions and if I simply use the above, will it not moan about MBR to GPT transfer?

Comment: You cannot use dd with gpt unless copying entire drive. Gpt has data in partition and that data must match data in primary & backup partition tables. You can use cp -a or rsync with various parameters to preserve ownership & permissions. With gpt you must have bios_grub partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @user3677331 I have used `dd` often to copy partitions.  Give me about an hour to make sure that I was copying between partition table types and check the effects.

Comment: @user3677331 By the way, I usually `dd` my partitions to an image, then `dd` the image to various drives.  I do this for quick distribution of new installs for clients.  The image would most likely be to timely and take up too mush space for you to use a full installation.

Comment: @user3677331  The copy from `MBR` to `GPT` went as expected.  I ran a checksum on the content of the `GPT` existing partition before and after the copy to a different partition from the `MBT`.  the `dd` copy only made changes to the destination partition.  All the other partitions remained untouched.  I'll update my question with broader details of the test.